# UIWebView stays blank when loading an HTML string

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` in my app and I'm attempting to use `loadHTMLString(_:, baseURL:)` to load HTML that's stored in a `String` in the app. The web view always shows up as a plain gray rectangle with no content. If I save the HTML string to a file and load it in Safari on my Mac, the page renders as expected.

I thought maybe it was something about the HTML so I've reduced it to a minimal test that gets the same results:

```
let myHTMLString = "<html><head></head><body><p>This is a test</p></body></html>"
myWebView.loadHTMLString(myHTMLString, baseURL: nil)
```

Still a gray rectangle.

I've browsed other answers here to check and verify various possibly-relevant details:

- Allowing arbitrary loads has no effect. Not that it should make a difference with my test case above, but some people have had problems with that.
- I've used Safari to remotely debug the `UIWebView`. All of the content is there, it's just not visible in the iOS app.
- The sizes shown when debugging from Safari match what I see if I use Xcode's view debugger. The web view is visible, and Safari shows that it's the right size.
- I've implemented `UIWebView` delegate methods and set the delegate property. I get calls to `webViewDidStartLoad(_:)`, `webViewDidFinishLoad(_:)`, and `webView(_:shouldStartLoadWith:navigationType:)`, and in the last case I always return `true`. No error is reported-- I never get a `webView(_:didFailLoadWithError:)`.
- If I change the background color of the `UIWebView` I get a different color of rectangle but I still don't get any visible page content.

What have I missed? This should be a trivial case but I get no visible content.

Comment: Are you sure your `UIWebView` is actually connected to `myWebView`?

Comment: @DonMag yes, I've verified that. Also if it weren't, most of my tests above would have failed (e.g. I would not see anything in Safari because I would not have loaded anything in the web view).

Comment: Well, that's odd... If you add a background color to the html string `<body bgcolor=#00ffff>` ... and use Debug View Hierarchy... do you see anything when selecting the Web View - such as this: https://imgur.com/a/BMRw3 - ? I know you don't see the text in the view, but do you see it in the Description pane?

Comment: No, the content doesn't show up there either.

Comment: ok... not sure how it's showing up in Safari debug? Anyway, next suggestion is to delete your UIWebView... add in a new one... set constraints... hook it up to your @IBOutlet... and see if you get any better results... or (I'm adding an answer so I can post code...)

Answer (score 1):

It's quite odd the error you're getting, but have you already tried to set a value for `baseURL`parameter? Something like: `URL(string: "www.google.com")`

Answer (score 1):

Try a fresh, empty UIViewController, with only this as the code:

```
import UIKit

class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let newWebView = UIWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 8, y: 8, width: 300, height: 400))
        self.view.addSubview(newWebView)

        // cyan background html
        let myHTMLString = "<html><head></head><body bgcolor=#00ffff><p>This is a test</p></body></html>"
        newWebView.loadHTMLString(myHTMLString, baseURL: nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

After investigating and trying a new project (inspired by @DonMag's answer), it looks like the problem is that the `UIWebView` was contained in a `UIStackView`. Although the web view's dimensions were correct, this somehow prevented it from rendering content. I've tried this in a simple test project and the behavior carries over-- a plain `UIWebView` on its own works fine, but one contained in a stack view doesn't render its content, even if its size is correct.

I don't know why that is or whether there's a trick I could use to get a web view to work correctly within a stack view. But the cause is clear, if not the reason.

Comment: Hmm... Sounds like it's down to constraints now. `UIWebView` doesn't have an intrinsic size, so when it's in a `UIStackView` things get wonky. I just tried it again... Vertical stack view containing label, uiwebview, label, uiview. Labels have intrinsic height... I gave the UIView width and height constraints. I gave the stack view width and height constraints. Set stack view to Fill / Fill... and the web view now sizes properly and its content is visible.

Comment: Fill/Fill is key. I had leading alignment, which I probably should have realized was wrong here. With fill/fill it works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: @TomHarrington, I am having the same issue. Tried everything but can't get the string to display. My webview is not in a Stackview, but I have alignments. Can you kindly tell me what you meant by fill? How did you get the webview to show the string? TIA

Comment: Fill here means the stack view settings for alignment and distribution, which you can set in interface builder or in code.